# Connect to Oracle using SSMA

Tags: database, oracle, sql-server-migration-assi

Hope you can help.  I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using SSMA for Oracle (v5.2.1259).  I have tried connecting to the remote database (Oracle 10g) and to a local database database (Oracle 11g) but neither is working.

What I would ideally like to do is to connect to the remote database and migrate the schema over.  I can connect to the remote database using Oracle SQL Developer but when I try with SSMA it doesn't work

In Oracle SQL Developer I am using Username SYS but I have to set the Role to SYSDBA and it lets me connect fine.  When I'm using SSMA I am using the following settings:

```
Provide: Oracle Client Provider
Mode: Standard Mode
Servername: same IP address used in SQL Developer
Server Port: 1521 (same as SQL Developer)
Oracle SID: PROD (same as SQL Developer)
User name: SYS (same as SQL Developer)
Password: same as SQL Developer
```

But when I try to connect from SSMA I get the error:

```
Conection to Oracle failed
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I tried setting up a local copy of the database and the same server as SSMA, again I can connect fine with SQL Developer but when I try to connect using SSMA I get the message

```
Connection to Oracle failed.
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

And I don't know how to connect using SSMA to have SYS connect as SYSDBA.

If someone could help that would be great.  Preferably to get me connected to the remote server but even connecting to the local one would do.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out I'm not allowed to use the SYS user to connect from a remote machine.  I created a new user and gave the user dba privileges and it all worked great.

Thanks

Alex