# SSMA Oracle Error While Collecting Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-migration-assi

I am encountering an error "Error While Collecting Data" even with successful connection.

[image: SSMA image]

How can I begin to troubleshoot this item?  I am using oracle 10.2.0

What are some alternatives to using SSMA to migrate data from Oracle to SQL Server?

This [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891739/connect-to-oracle-using-ssma) says it may be a permissions issue along with the following blog.

[Permissions Blog](https://ssma.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/common-requirement-user-does-not-have-required-permissions/)